# It's October 2018. ./bitcoin-qt -reindex-chainstate takes forever. Is there a way to speed this up?

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, peers, reindex

Current version: Bitcoin Core 0.16.3

I think I have a corrupted blockchain download as my VM box was shut down in the middle of syncing. Which is why I'm doing a -reindex-chainstate

I have the entire Bitcoin blockchain synced at (250+gb), but its been stuck on "connecting to peers" for the past 12 hours. So this is why I'm assuming I need to do a -reindex

Is there a faster way of syncing -reindex as of October 2018? I read a few other solutions but its for older versions of Bitcoin core.

Comment: Set your dbcache config as high as your system permits.

Comment: I've put the dbcache in my bitcoin.conf file and started up bitcoin-qt again. Is there a way to confirm the dbcache is changed via the qt gui? thanks!