# Even with dbcache=7000 and 16 core processor. Why does -reindex-chainstate take more than 24+ hours?

Tags: bitcoin-core, reindex

My computer got shut off due to a power outage and when I rebooted my bitcoin core it was stuck on connecting to peers. I was told to do a -reindex-chainstate with dbcache set as high as possible. Even with these high settings of dbcache=7000 and 16 core cpu, why does reindexing take more than 24+ hours? Also I'm not using a SSD, but a regular HDD.

Comment: What does "suck on connecting to peers" mean?  And what told you to do a reindex chainstate?

Comment: Mr. Pieter told me to. see: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/79760/its-october-2018-bitcoin-qt-reindex-chainstate-takes-forever-is-there-a-wa

Comment: Nowhere in that are you told to reindex.

Comment: Your right. he just mentions dbcache. I must have gotten it from another related question where someone had the same issue of connecting to peers. This happened right after my VM box got shut off unexpectedly.

Comment: Do you have pruning turned on?

Comment: no i do not have pruning turned on.